# How can I create this ticket shape in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to build a ticket shaped container in flutter like this:
[image]

I'm trying to use the ClipPath widget but I don't know how to get the path right.

Answer (score 3):

Use the following `CustomClipper` to create the shape then, inside the clipPath widget, call the constructor of this class `CustomTicketShape()`.

The class is below:

```
class CustomTicketShape extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    final path = Path()
      ..lineTo(0, size.height / 2 - 20)
      ..quadraticBezierTo(
          size.width * 0.10, size.height / 2, 0, size.height / 2 + 20)
      ..lineTo(0, size.height)
      ..lineTo(size.width, size.height)
      ..lineTo(size.width, size.height / 2 + 20)
      ..quadraticBezierTo(
          size.width * 0.90, size.height / 2, size.width, size.height / 2 - 20)
      ..lineTo(size.width, 0);

    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can either use a `CustomeClipper` or a `Stack` to get this ticket shape. See the below code to get this shape using Stack:

```
Stack(
alignment: Alignment.center,
 children: [
    Container(
       height: 100,
       width: 200,
       color: Colors.black,
    ),
    Positioned(
      left: -5,
      child: Container(
               height: 20,
               width: 20,
               decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  shape: BoxShape.circle
                    ),
              )),
   Positioned(
     right: -5,
     child: Container(
               height: 20,
               width: 20,
               decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                 color: Colors.white,
                 shape: BoxShape.circle
                 ),
               )),
            ],
          )
```

### Output:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try below code and Refer [`flutter_ticket_widget`](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_ticket_widget) package

```
 FlutterTicketWidget(
          width: 400,
          height: 200,
          isCornerRounded: true,
          child: Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            color: Colors.blue,
            child: Text(
              'Add your widget here',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 20,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

Your result screen-> [image]

Refer other packages [fw_ticket](https://pub.dev/packages/fw_ticket), [ticketview](https://pub.dev/packages/ticketview)

Answer (score 1):

I got this to work in the end by following this : https://www.flutterclutter.dev/flutter/tutorials/how-to-cut-a-hole-in-an-overlay/2020/510/

```dart
class SCticketShape extends StatelessWidget {
  const SCticketShape({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ClipPath(
        clipper: CustomTicketShape(),
        child: Container(
        color: Colors.lightBlue,
          height: 0.3.sh,
          width: 0.9.sw,
        ),
      );
  }
}

class CustomTicketShape extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    final path = Path();
    path.addRRect(
      RRect.fromRectAndRadius(
      Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, size.width, size.height), 
      Radius.circular(8)));
      path.addOval(
        Rect.fromCircle(
          center: Offset(0, (size.height/3) *1.8), 
          radius: 15));
      path.addOval(
        Rect.fromCircle(
          center: Offset(size.width, (size.height/3) *1.8), 
          radius: 15));
      path.fillType = PathFillType.evenOdd;
  return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper oldClipper) {
    return true;
  }
```