# How to design a half-drilled border like this with flutter

Tags: flutter, widget

I recently started learning **Flutter**, and I attempted to solve this issue on my own before asking this question, but I was unsuccessful. I tried using a `Stack` layout and a `CustomPainter` class, but I couldn't achieve the desired effect, especially for the shadow part. I'm unsure how to handle it.

Could you please explain how to achieve this hollow effect when adding it to the centre part of the component?

[This is how the widget Looks likes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DA5TN.png)

Comment: The easiest way to do that is to have that shape as a png and use that as background

Comment: And on top of the other semi-answers, maybe have a look at the answers to https://stackoverflow.com/q/71404706/11846040, which you may be able to adjust to get what you desire.